# vue-cli upgrade from v3 to v4 breaks build process with thread-loader error: Cannot read property 'options' of undefined

Tags: webpack, vue-cli

I just upgraded vue-cli from v3 to v4. Development mode works! But build process errors out with:

```
 error  in ./src/App/components/AppLayout.vue?vue&type=script&lang=js&

Module build failed (from ./node_modules/thread-loader/dist/cjs.js):
Thread Loader (Worker 0)
Cannot read property 'options' of undefined
    at PoolWorker.fromErrorObj (/home/vsonline/workspace/node_modules/thread-loader/dist/WorkerPool.js:26
2:12)
    at /home/vsonline/workspace/node_modules/thread-loader/dist/WorkerPool.js:204:29
    at mapSeries (/home/vsonline/workspace/node_modules/neo-async/async.js:3625:14)
    at PoolWorker.onWorkerMessage (/home/vsonline/workspace/node_modules/thread-loader/dist/WorkerPool.js
:170:35)
    at /home/vsonline/workspace/node_modules/thread-loader/dist/WorkerPool.js:152:14
    at Socket.onChunk (/home/vsonline/workspace/node_modules/thread-loader/dist/readBuffer.js:36:9)
    at Object.loader (/home/vsonline/workspace/node_modules/vue-inheritance-loader/src/index.js:26:32)

 @ ./src/App/components/AppLayout.vue?vue&type=script&lang=js& 1:0-458 1:474-477 1:479-934 1:479-934
 @ ./src/App/components/AppLayout.vue
 @ ./src/App/router/index.js
 @ ./src/main.ts
 @ multi ./src/main.ts
```

Comment: `vue.config.js`: `parallel: false`, allows me to avoid this problem

Comment: Crow, Thank you so much !

Comment: @Crow Hey man this worked fine and dandy, thanks!, Can you give us some explanation on why this error appear suddenly and why this property works on false

Comment: @Mavro I don't know why `thread-loader` fails. But by disabling parallel option, you probably avoid using `thread-loader` at all. So this is sacrificing possible performance (multi threading) for stability.
I quit using `vue-cli` some time ago. `Vite` seems like a superior choice. That's why I avoid this problem instead of solving this. I think that it is not worth the time to invest in `vue-cli`.

Answer (score 4):

vue.config.js: parallel: false is working for me.